# Define fmap in terms of the Data typeclass

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming

Can one define `fmap` in terms of the `Data` typeclass from [`Data.Data`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Data.html)?

It seems that using `gfoldl` one could not modify types.. Are there other combinators which can do this?

I'm guessing that it can't be done *in the general case* as one would have no way of only affecting the "`Right`" `a`'s in an `Either a a`, but perhaps it could be done for some cases such as `Maybe`?

(I know that `fmap` is easily derivable but am still interested in whether this is achievable using `Data`)

Comment: There is an example using `syb` given [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate) at the bottom. It uses `unsafeCoerce`; not sure if there is a less disgusting way of doing it.

Comment: @jberryman: you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's on example using `syb` from [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Generics
import Unsafe.Coerce

{- | C tags the type that is actually parameterized, so to avoid touching the
Int when a ~ Int:

> data T a = T Int a

by changing the type (not representation) to:

> x :: T Int (C Int)
-}
newtype C a = C a deriving (Data,Typeable)

fmapData :: forall t a b. (Typeable a, Data (t (C a)), Data (t a)) =>
    (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
fmapData f input = uc . everywhere (mkT $ \(x::C a) -> uc (f (uc x)))
                    $ (uc input :: t (C a))
    where uc = unsafeCoerce
```